# ValidationSummary hyperlink doesn't change tab

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, validationsummary, pagecontrol

Im using devexpress `Html.DevExpress().ValidationSummary` in my mvc project. My form contains a devexpress page control with 3 tabs. When there are client-side validation errors validation summary shows them, and every error is hyperlink. If you click it, the field with error is focused, but if the field is on other tab nothing happens. So the field is focused if it is on active tab. I'd like it to change the active tab and focus appropriate field. Is there a way to make it work right?

Comment: DevExpress version - 13.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague solved this problem using javascript and jQuery:

```
var nameControlTab = "myPageControl"; //name of your pagecontrol here

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("tbody").on('click', 'a[href*="javascript:_aspxVSOnErrorClick("]', function () {

            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            url = url.substring(url.indexOf("'") + 1);
            url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("'"));

            var idTab = $("#" + url + "_ET").parents('div[id*="' + nameControlTab + '_C"]').not(nameControlTab + '_CC')[0].id;

            var indexTab = idTab.substring((nameControlTab + '_C').length);

            SetTab(indexTab);

            return true;
        });
    });

function indexOf(array, value) {
        if ([].indexOf)
            return array.indexOf(value);
        else {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                if (array[i] == value)
                    return i;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    function SetTab(indexTab) {
        this[nameControlTab].SetActiveTabIndex(indexTab);
    }
```